# How can I add data from the Firebase database in a reversed order?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently developing a chat app. The problem is, that when someone types something it shows randomly on the chat screen (after a user registered and logged in).

I want it to look like a normal chat app, so the last message should be at the bottom of the screen. I even reversed the data and list view, but it didn't work.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:naber/constants.dart';

final _firestore=FirebaseFirestore.instance;
User loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id="chat_screen";
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {

  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String messageText;

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser()async{
    try{
      final currentUser =  await _auth.currentUser;
      if(currentUser!=null){
        loggedInUser=currentUser;
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            MessagesStream(),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.data()['text'];
          final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];

          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
          );

          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubble({this.sender, this.text, this.isMe});

  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool isMe;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
        isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            sender,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.0,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            borderRadius: isMe
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0))
                : BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            elevation: 5.0,
            color: isMe ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black54,
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, It make sense to create a part which is called createdAt on firebas, but unfortunately, after I applied your code part, I started not to see anything on chatscreen, I dont understand why.

Comment: Well.... I had a typo in the query that I just fixed, so yo might want to try that.

Comment: Now it works, :) Hava a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add messages with:

```
_firestore.collection('messages').add({
  'text': messageText,
  'sender': loggedInUser.email,
});
```

Firestore doesn't have any built-in default ordering for documents. If you want to be able to order the documents, you will need to add a value to each document to allow that.

For example, you could add a timestamp of when the document was created with:

```
_firestore.collection('messages').add({
  'text': messageText,
  'sender': loggedInUser.email,
  'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
```

By using [`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/serverTimestamp.html) the server will automatically populate this field, which you can then use when reading the data with:

```
stream: _firestore.collection('messages').orderBy('createdAt', descending: true).snapshots()
```